# C# how to filter report viewer using Parameter

Tags: c#, sql, filter, report, rdlc

So this is frustrating can't manage to filter the report viewer, I've tried many online tutorials by the way none of them helps. so this is my code for showing the items in my table`AddPoTbl` to report viewer.

```
CmbViewPo();
ItemDataSet m = new ItemDataSet();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM AddPoTbl", con);
da.Fill(m, m.Tables[0].TableName);

ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("PoDataSet", m.Tables[0]);
this.reportViewPo.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
this.reportViewPo.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
this.reportViewPo.LocalReport.Refresh();
this.reportViewPo.RefreshReport();
```

I want to filter it with value of my Combo-box or a parameter that holds the value of the Combo-box.
I have tried filtering its row in the `tablix` and many more
please help me with this.

Thank you !

Comment: select * from AddPoTbl where fieldName=@filterValue or whatever

Comment: just what I said in code: https://www.aspforums.net/Threads/567589/Filter-RDLC-Report-based-on-TextBox-using-C-and-VBNet-in-ASPNet/

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Parameter for the column to be Filtered.

- Right click on the Table in the Report
- Properties
- Filters
- Add Expression, Operator
- Choose the Parameter as a Filter

That's all.  Please watch the below video for more details.

https://youtu.be/psLVbNx0GtU?t=358

[image]